# How to use swift in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, multiplatform

I am coding an application using Swift for six months. I recently discovered Flutter. Is it possible to exploit the whole Swift project on Flutter? If not, are there alternatives? I don't want to start all over again at 0.

Comment: Flutter makes the binaries that will render natively on a target mobile device. It doesn't parse Dart into Swift/Java/Kotlin, in fact it makes an XCode project and an Android Studio project which calls and run those binaries.

Comment: Ok thank you!  so I can't use my project using Swift and I have to code everything using Dart?

Comment: Yes. But also after generating an IOS project from Flutter, you have the freedom to modify it.